# Variable in Async function not re-evaluated in while-True loop

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I made a dummy server to test my websockets application against. It listens to `subscription` messages, then gives information about those subscriptions through the socket.

The class' `subscriptions` attribute is empty at initialisation and should fill up as the `listen()` function receives subscription messages. However, it seems as though `self.subscriptions` in `talk()` is never appended to, leaving it stuck in its infinite while-loop and never transmitting messages.

The problem is solved by adding a line `await asyncio.sleep(1)` after the for-loop. But why? Shouldn't `self.subscriptions` be re-evaluated every time the for-loop is started?

Code below:

```
class DummyServer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.subscriptions = []

    def start(self):
        return websockets.serve(self.handle, 'localhost', 8765)

    async def handle(self, websocket, path):
        self.ws = websocket
        listen_task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.listen())
        talk_task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.talk())

        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
            [listen_task, talk_task],
            return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED
        )

        for task in pending:
            task.cancel()

    async def listen(self):
        while True:
            try:
                msg = await self.ws.recv()
                msg = json.loads(msg)
                await self.triage(msg)  # handles subscriptions
            except Exception as e:
                await self.close()
                break

    async def talk(self):
        while True:
            for s in self.subscriptions:
                dummy_data = {
                    'product_id': s
                }
                try:
                    await self.send(json.dumps(dummy_data))
                except Exception as e:
                    await self.close()
                    break

            await asyncio.sleep(1)  # without this line, no message is ever sent
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the start of your function, `subscriptions` is empty and the `for` body is not evaluated. As a result, your coroutine is virtually the same as:

```
async def talk(self):
    while True:
        pass
```

The while-loop does not contain a "context switching point", meaning that the `asyncio` event loop basically hangs there, forever executing the **blocking** while loop.

Adding `await sleep()` breaks the magic circle; even `await sleep(0)` could help.

Clever code should probably make use of `asyncio.Condition` in combination with `self.subscriptions`, but this matter goes beyond the  scope of your original question.

Comment: Thanks! I'm only just getting to grips with asyncio. Your comment helped me understand that an await is necessary to allow a context switch.